# Наследование классов в ООП на python

Tags: python, ооп

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: Нужно подсчитать количество клиентов. В моём случае, я подумал создать в экземплярах класса последнее поле (popularity) и подсчитать их сумму
То есть количество клиентов: это popularity класса Econom + popularity класса Usual_Tarif и т.д
То есть ответ должен быть такой: 
количество клиентов = 30 000 + 50 000 + 43 000 + 71 000 = 194 000
Но как их суммировать не могу сообразить

```
class Usual_Tarif:
    def __init__(self, name, calls, internet, price, popularity):
        self.name = name
        self.type = calls
        self.internet = internet
        self.price = price
        self.popularity = popularity


class Econom(Usual_Tarif):
    pass


class Smart(Usual_Tarif):
    pass


class Unlimited(Usual_Tarif):
    pass


class Client:
    pass


# **********  Все тарифы  ****************
econom = Econom("Эконом", 60, 1000, 60, 30000)
# 60 (минут) звонки; Интернет: 1000 МБ; Цена: 60 (грн/мес), 30000 тисяч клиентов
usual = Usual_Tarif("Стандарт", 90, 750, 45, 50000)
smart = Smart("Развлечение без границ", 200, 2500, 125, 43000)
unlimited = Unlimited("Полный безлимит", 1440, 100000, 250, 71000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если вы хотите при каждом инстанцировании класса увеличивать некий глобальный счетчик, то нужно поле `popularity` объявить не на уровне экземпляра, а на уровне класса, и обращаться к нему по имени класса:

```py
class Usual_Tarif:

    POPULARITY = 0

    def __init__(self, name, calls, internet, price, popularity):
        self.name = name
        self.type = calls
        self.internet = internet
        self.price = price
        Usual_Tarif.POPULARITY += popularity
```

2. Но я бы так не делал, так как такой код сложнее поддерживать и понимать, и глобальные переменные это как известно антипаттерн. Как по мне, лучше выделить интерфейс `Tariff`, и другим классам реализовывать этот интерфейс. Ну а дальше работать с этими тарифами без углубления в реализацию

```py
class Tariff:
    def popularity(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Econom(Tarif):
    def __init__(self, popularity):
        self._popularity = popularity

    def popularity() -> int:
        return self._popularity


class Smart(Tarif):
    def __init__(self, popularity):
        self._popularity = popularity

    def popularity() -> int:
        return self._popularity


class Unlimited(Usual_Tarif):
    def __init__(self, popularity):
        self._popularity = popularity

    def popularity() -> int:
        return self._popularity

total_popularity = sum(t.popularity() for t in [econom, usual, smart, unlimited])
```

3. Я конечно не в курсе вашей доменной области. Но то, что тариф знает о количестве человек, которые его используют — это странно. Тут скорее наоборот, человек должен знать, какой тариф использовать. А если нужно посчитать распределение тарифов, то должна быть уже другая сущность, например `TariffReport`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня так не получилось сделать